# How to target a title bar in a specific jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have multiple grids on the screen at the same time and I would like to show a message in a specific one.

This code works well but attaches to all the grids.

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar").append("<span>Error Message</span>");
```

How do I target a specific grid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setCaption` method of jqGrid to change the title:

```
$("#grid1").jqGrid("setCaption", "Error Message");
```

**UPDATED**: The parameter of `setCaption` can be **any HTML fragment**. Thus you can use

```
$("#grid1").jqGrid("setCaption", "<span style='color:red'>Error Message</span>");
```

or even better

```
$("#grid1").jqGrid("setCaption",
    "<span class='ui-state-error-text'>Error Message</span>");
```

Comment: Thank you but what if I want to change the color and highlight only the error while retaining the existing caption?  

I have been able to add and remove a div or span (I have tried several things) and it works fine but I only want to append to the .ui-jqgrid-titlebar that pertains to the jqgrid where there is a user input error.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @RayMarsh: The parameter of `setCaption` can be any HTML fragment. Thus you can use `$("#grid1").jqGrid("setCaption", "<span style='color:red'>Error Message</span>");` for example or better `$("#grid1").jqGrid("setCaption", "<span class='ui-state-error-text'>Error Message</span>");`.